# PHP splitting a string into an array

Tags: php

I am trying to split an string into an array. This is my data:

```
1. Some text is here!!! 2. Some text again 3. SOME MORE TEXT !!!
```

I would like an array to be like this:

```
Array(
 [0] => '1. Some text here!!!
 [1] => '2. Some text again
 etc..
);
```

I tried this using preg_split but can't get it right

---

```
$text = "1. Some text is here!!! 2. Some text again 3. SOME MORE TEXT !!!";
$array = preg_split('/[0-9]+./', $text, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($array);
```

Comment: could you please post your code here???

Comment: You need to include the string after the "/[0-9]+./" regexp. 
For example: /[1-9].\s[a-zA-Z\s\!]*/g
Check out this test: [link](http://regexr.com?37gad)

Comment: No because it is not always 1. it can be 2. etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
$text  = "1. Some text is here333!!! 2. Some text again 3. SOME MORE TEXT !!!";
$array = preg_split('/(\d+\..*?)(?=\d\.)/', $text, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

print_r($array);
Array
(
    [0] => 1. Some text is here333!!! 
    [1] => 2. Some text again 
    [2] => 3. SOME MORE TEXT !!!
)
```

**Why it works?**

First of all, `preg_split` by default doesn't keep the delimiters after splitting a string. That's why your code doesn't contain number e.g. 1, 2 etc

Secondly, when using `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` you must provide `()` capturing pattern in your regex

**UPDATED**

Updated regex to support number in string

Comment: @Reziged can you please explain the solution?

Comment: You are capturing only the delimiter, witch is smart. But regexp will fail when you have digit in **text** e.g. `$text  = "1. Some text. 3 test 2. Some text`. Delimer `[0-9]\\.` looks more safe

Comment: @Nomi I've added the explanation to the post

Comment: Oh I just noticed that if a string has a number in it like this:
1. Some text with number 2, 3, wahtever It breaks on the "2," and "3,". Can this be avoided?

Comment: @MouNtant Here you go, try again with new regex

Comment: Thank you this one is correct. Though i made one modification : /(\d+\..*?)(?=\d+\.)/ So it detects multiple digits

Comment: @MouNtant that's great! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "1. Some text is here!!! 2. Some text again 3. SOME MORE TEXT !!!";

preg_match_all('#[0-9]+\\.#', $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);


$exploded = array();
$previous = null;
foreach ( $matches[0] as $item ) {
    if ( $previous !== null ) {
        $exploded[] = substr($str, $previous, $item[1]);
    }
    $previous = $item[1];
}
if ( $previous !== null ) {
    $exploded[] = substr($str, $previous);
}

var_export($exploded);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$a = '1. Some text is here!!! 2. Some text again 3. SOME MORE TEXT !!!';

$array = preg_split('/([0-9]+\\.)/', $a, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

var_dump($array);
```

Result:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => string '1.' (length=2)
  1 => string ' Some text is here!!! ' (length=22)
  2 => string '2.' (length=2)
  3 => string ' Some text again ' (length=17)
  4 => string '3.' (length=2)
  5 => string ' SOME MORE TEXT !!!' (length=19)
```

Then you have to concatenate 1st and 2nd index, 3rd and 4th etc....